# Using jquery with Angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I want to show a bootstrap modal but im still getting

```
SectionDetailComponent.html:54 ERROR TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
```

My .angular-cli:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

My component:

```
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $:any;
```

Comment: instead of using regular bootstrap.js you should try ngx-bootstrap or `ng-bootstrap` for using bootstrap 4 .https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home . it is designed specifically for Angular 4

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my real problem was Popper.js, I just had to add inside scripts after jquery and before bootstrap

Comment: Angular versions of Bootstrap (ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap) work better and more naturally with Angular than Bootstrap + jQuery. Note: I did not downvote anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

Comment: honestly there's no need to even use jquery with angular. Angular's built in libs can do everything that jquery does.